# Работа с Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

У меня есть несколько файлов, которые находятся в разных директориях

*back/Makefile*

*back/core/main.c*

*back/core/src/*.c*

**Makefile:**

```
TARGET = Server
CC = gcc

PREF_ = ./core/src/

SRC = $(wildcard core/src/*.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
    $(CC)  core/main.o $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET)

main.o : core/main.c
    $(CC) -c core/main.c -o main.o

%.o : $(PREF_)%.c core/main.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@       

clean : 
    rm $(TARGET) *.o
```

Так как, main.c не находится в той же директории, что и остальные единицы трансляции, то он не будет собираться с этим кодом, я добавил его как отдельную задачу, но при сборке будто просто пропускается, если его собрать отдельно, а потом запустить Makefile, тогда все работает хорошо. Но как мне сделать, чтобы main.c тоже собирался через Makefile

Comment: Добавьте его в `SRC`

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо

Comment: @user7860670 Кстати, а если я хочу чтобы все файлы *.o переместились в другую директорию, например, bin, могу ли я просто указать этот путь при компиляции? `OUTPUT = ./bin/ $(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
 $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(OUTPUT)$(TARGET)

%.o : $(PREF_)%.c
 $(CC) -c $< -o $(OUTPUT)$@  `

Comment: Лучше их сразу создавать в правильной папке.

Comment: @user7860670 А как тогда настроить, чтобы они создавались сразу в другой папке? У меня получается готовый файл поместить только в bin, а остальные лежат в src, не хочу чтобы был мусор :)